# would the native says: From the very first day he shows us that he is a man who takes no lip off nobody

Tags: present-tense, present-simple

Is the use of the simple present correct in the example bel:

**From the very first day he shows us that he is a man who takes no lip off nobody **

Comment: why do you think it is correct or incorrect?  You're supposed to show you've done some research yourself.

Comment: "a man who takes no lip off nobody" - a Cockney or someone speaking in a very casual UK register might say that.

Comment: I do not think it is correct. I heard a native speaker who used the phrase "from the very first day" and then followed it with the present simple. However, when I searched online, I only found sentences use past tenses or present perfect after such phrase.